# Why would a scammer ask for creation of a new email account?

Tags: email, phishing, scam

I recently received the following email:

> Good day my dear friend,
>   I am contacting you to help get the deposit (£8.5 million pounds), my late
>   client Engineer Alexander left in his Bank before his sudden death with
>   his wife and their only daughter to avoid confiscation.
>   For more information about this transaction to continue with me on our
>   E-mail: [scammer's email redacted] or you can provide your private E-mail
>   address, so that I can write to you with details.
>   I find it very difficult to send this items to you because of your
>   differences domain / IP. I suggest you create a yahoo.com, Hotmail.com or
>   gmail.com and reply me through it easily our correspondence. With kind regards and best wishes, Barrister Dr.Simon peter Esq....
>
> [Message clipped] View entire message

Sadly, I can't help out Barrister Dr. Simon Peter Esq as I tend to get a terrible rash in the presence of large sums of money. However, this part of the email caught my eye:

> I find it very difficult to send this items to you because of your
>   differences domain / IP. I suggest you create a yahoo.com, Hotmail.com or
>   gmail.com and reply me through it easily our correspondence.

This seems to match up as I got this email in a zoho.eu inbox using a custom domain.

**Why would they ask for creation of a new account on a popular mail site?**

Comment: Are the yahoo.com... links legit? Could be a phishing link.

Comment: Everything was plaintext, there were no links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, where did you receive this e-mail? If it was a corporate/business domain, then they're probably trying to set up a side channel so they can lure you outside the "protection"/oversight of your infosec team.

Comment: or they have mapped out the protection mechanisms of yahoo/hotmail/gmail and know how to get around them